# Issue to load data from java servlet after clicking submit button

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, mariadb

I am using j2e. I have my .jsp where I have some select-options, some information that I get from a database, and a submit button that permit to update the database with the information I choose on the web page. Once I click this submit button, the web page reloads, but displays the information wrongly, without the information from the database. It seems like it is not doing the doGet() after the doPost.

It is going from this :[image: before the click]

To this :[image: after the click]

I tried to change the path of the redirect from the doPost method, by redirecting directly to the servlet instead of the .jsp, but it's not working.

Here is my .jsp :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Création d'équipe</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Choisissez le nombre d'équipe à créer :

            <!-- REPRENDRE CA ET FAIRE EN SORTE QU'ON PUISSE FAIRE SEULEMENT 
            LE NOMBRE D'EQUIPE QU'ON A RENSEIGNE !! -->

    <form method="post">
            <label for="nbrEkip" name="nbrEkip">Nombre d'équipe à créer : </label>
                <select name="nbrEkip">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                </select>
    </form>
</p>

<%-- <p>
        <p>Bonjour ${ etudiant.prenom } ${ etudiant.nom } ! Vous êtes un ${ etudiant.genre }</p>
</p> --%>

<p>Etudiants sans équipe :
    <ul>
        <c:forEach var="etudiant" items="${ etudiants }">
            <c:if test="${ etudiant.idEkip == '0' }">   
                <li><c:out value="${ etudiant.prenom }"/> <c:out value="${ etudiant.nom }"/></li>
            </c:if> 
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
    Equipes :
    <ul>
        <c:forEach var="ekip" items="${ ekips }">
            <li>nom d'équipe : <c:out value="${ ekip.nom }"/> <br>numéro d'équipe = <c:out value="${ ekip.id }"/></li>
                Composition : <c:forEach var="etudiant" items="${ ekip.etudiants }">
                        <c:out value="${ etudiant.prenom }"/> <c:out value="${ etudiant.nom }"/>
                </c:forEach>        
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
</p>
<p>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="ajEtudiant" name="ajEtudiant">Ajouter un étudiant à une équipe : </label>
        <select name="selectEtudiant">
            <c:forEach var="etudiant" items="${ etudiants }">
                <c:if test="${ etudiant.idEkip == '0' }">   
                    <option value="${ etudiant.prenom } ${ etudiant.nom }"><c:out value="${ etudiant.prenom }"/> <c:out value="${ etudiant.nom }"/></option>
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
        <select name="valueEkip">
            <c:forEach var="ekip" items="${ ekips }">
                    <option value="${ ekip.id }"><c:out value="${ ekip.nom }"/></option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Envoyer</button>
    </form>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my servlet :

```
package com.octest.servlets;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;

import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.octest.beans.Auteur;
import com.octest.beans.Ekip;
import com.octest.beans.Etudiant;
import com.octest.bdd.*;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class servletProject2
 */
public class servletProject2 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    public servletProject2() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Utilisateur tableEtudiant = new Utilisateur();
        request.setAttribute("etudiants", tableEtudiant.recupererEtudiant());
        
        Ekips tableEkip = new Ekips();
        request.setAttribute("ekips", tableEkip.recupererEkip());
        
        /*System.out.println(request.getParameter("idEkip"));
        RecupEtu etudiantsEkip = new RecupEtu();
        request.setAttribute("recupEtu", etudiantsEkip.recupererEtudiantsEkip(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("idEkip"))));
        */
        
        
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/ekip.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String prenomNom = request.getParameter("selectEtudiant");
        String[] tabpn = prenomNom.split(" ");
        String prenom = tabpn[0];
        String nom = tabpn[1];
        
        AjEtuEkip ajEtuEkip = new AjEtuEkip();
        
        try {
            ajEtuEkip.ajouterEtuEkip(prenom, nom, Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valueEkip")));
//          response.sendRedirect("ekip.jsp");
        } catch (NumberFormatException | SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
//          System.out.println("nom : " + nom + prenom);
            System.out.println("Problème ajout");
        }

        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/ekip.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: Define it's not working. How did you redirect to a servlet?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the servlet is not been requested when you click your form.
This cause that variables you're calling to fill your form doesn't exist at all.

The first time you enter to your url, the servlet is taking the request, getting all database info an then processing jsp.

But when you click submit in your form, you are just reloading the jsp without calling the servlet.

This can be avoided using url mapping.

In your web.xml file you can add that the url you use `{/my-url}` shows `{your-scriptlet.jsp}`

Now, the form doesn't have an `action="/url"` attribute on your `<form>` tag. This makes your form to target the url your servlet is listening for.

Let me know if it was helpful c: